# How to keep 5 cards in the same row using col-sm-3

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am currently working on cards in HTML I am trying to put 5 cards in same row without breaking into new row.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 1 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 2 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 3 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 4 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 5 </div>
</div>
```

I tried using col-sm-2 but it is too small for the content inside the card.

[how it looks currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlEMK.png)

Can't I just remove the margin-left and right border? I thought no-gutters did that. I wanted to bring the card in the second row to the first row.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes bootstrap isn't the best way.  Try flexbox.  It's easy.

```css
.row{
display:flex ;
justify-content:space-between;
}

.col-sm-3{
border:solid 1px black;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 1 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 2 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 3 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 4 </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"> Card 5 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! I tried but I still have gaps, is it because of the content inside col-sm-3?

https://imgur.com/3fi2N1i

Comment: no, we can make the gaps go away.  give me a minute or two and I'll update the snippet

Comment: snippet updated.  Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If using [Bootstrap 4.6](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#equal-width), you can use simply `col` or `col-[breakpoint]` for equal width columns:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
   <div class="col-sm"> Card 1 </div>
   <div class="col-sm"> Card 2 </div>
   <div class="col-sm"> Card 3 </div>
   <div class="col-sm"> Card 4 </div>
   <div class="col-sm"> Card 5 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. try reading more about the grid system , Heres [a link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)